# How do I Reference Components in Angular2?

Tags: angular

I define a component in a separate file in the root folder:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'testtag',
  templateUrl: './simplecomponent.component.html',
})

export class SimpleComponent {

}
```

I then try to import it so that the main component can use it like so:

```
import {SimpleComponent} from './simplecomponent.component.ts'
```

I then get the following error:

> VM360 zone.js:192 Error: (SystemJS) ReferenceError: SimpleComponent is not defined

Here is the [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/jfyqUXJnPX0c9J8TRVrZ?p=preview). Relevant code is in src/app.ts. Note, the `SimpleComponent` works if uncommented here - the problem is moving it to another file and referencing it.

Also, how do I "attach" a component to a module. In angular 1, I just did:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(name, function);
```

Is it just a matter of adding it to the `declarations`, regardless of where the file is located?

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ SimpleComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the relative path of the component file you want to refer inside another. Use ./ and ../ and dir names to demonstrate where to find the refered file from the current file location. For example, if you are trying to import ComponentB inside ComponentA:

- If both component files are in the same dir, on ComponentA you need:

  `import { ComponentB } from './componentB';`

  **(./ stands for "this same directory")**
- If ComponentB is on the parent directory of ComponentA, you need:

  `import { ComponentB } from '../componentB';`

  **(../ stands for "parent directory", while ../../ stands for "grandparent directory", and so on).**
- If ComponentB is on a subdirectory of where ComponentA is located, you need to mention that dir name, starting from the current dir (./):

  `import { ComponentB } from './subDirB/componentB';`
- If ComponentB is on a sibling directory of where ComponentA is located, then you need to mix things:

  `import { ComponentB } from '../subDirB/componentB';`

Answer (score 1):

You just got your paths wrong...

```
import {SimpleComponent} from '../simplecomponent.component.ts'
```

Your app.ts is one directory lower than simplecomponent.component.ts - the paths are relative.